# how to print the each column separated by dot in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am a beginner to PL/SQL. Consider I have three tables: `emp`, `organization`, `emp_detail`. Refer the image to know the table Schema, and result format.

[image: click to view the image]

I can get the result by joining these three tables based on the `emp_id` but I don't know how to print the dots (`....`) in the result.

Comment: Can a person work for several organizations? Is the salary the total, or per organization?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Your data model is seriously flawed.  You have 3 tables, each with emp_id as (apparently) the primary key.  From what we see here you really should have only 1 table with emp_id, emp_name, organization, and salary.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how; I don't have your tables (and don't feel like creating ones, as you didn't feel like providing test case yourself) so I used Scott's `EMP`.

If you don't care about nice alignment, omit `RPAD` function call and just concatenate desired number of dots.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select empno, ename, job from emp where deptno = 10) loop
  3      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.empno ||'.....'||
  4                           rpad(cur_r.ename, 15, '.') ||
  5                           cur_r.job
  6                          );
  7    end loop;
  8  end;
  9  /
7782.....CLARK..........MANAGER
7839.....KING...........PRESIDENT
7934.....MILLER.........CLERK

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(emp_id as varchar2(5)) || '....' || emp_name || '....' || organisation || '....' 
|| cast(salary as varchar2(10)) 
from emp 
join organisation on emp.emp_id=organisation.emp_id
join emp_details on emp.emp_id=emp_details.emp_id
```